# Extract mail body of outlook using javascript function

Tags: javascript, typescript, outlook

I am trying to get the body of my outlook mail using javascript. Currently i am able to extract title but not body.

```
document.getElementById("fill-data").onclick = function () {
        var item = Office.context.mailbox.item;
        var bodyContent;
        Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('text', function (async) {bodyContent = async.value});
        document.getElementById("txt-subject").value = item.subject;
       // The below code returns "undefined"
        document.getElementById("txt-description").value = bodyContent;  
    };
```

Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync('text', function (async) {bodyContent = async.value}); is not returning body instead it returns "undefined" into my textbox .How can i extract body of outlook mail?

Comment: java is to javascript as ham is to hamster (that is: utterly, completely, entirely unrelated). Removed the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
    'text', 
    function (async) {bodyContent = async.value}
);
```

sets the value of `bodyContent` in its callback. The callback is invoked ***asynchronously*** (i.e. the call to `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync` does not block).

This means that by the time you

```
document.getElementById("txt-description").value = bodyContent;
```

that callback function has not yet been invoked and `bodyContent` has not been assigned to

Don't set the `value` until the callback has been invoked. How? Just doing it in the callback would be one way.

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync(
    'text', 
    function (result) {
        document.getElementById("txt-description").value = result.value;
    }
);
```

Side-note: I'd strongly recommend against the variable-name `async`, even if your environment allows it.